# Unexpected result from Date() function

Tags: php, function, date

Can any one explain to me why the line of code:

```
Date("l F d, Y","2013-01-25T01:42:16.411Z")
```

Is returning:

```
Wednesday December 31, 1969
```

And not:

```
Wednesday January 25, 2013
```

Comment: -1 for not reading the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter for [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is a Unix timestamp, not a formatted string:

```
date("l F d, Y",strtotime("2013-01-25T01:42:16.411Z"));
```

I used [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert it to a Unix timestamp before formatting it with `date()`;